# No json file could be decoded but if i open a specific file name it works

Tags: python, json, anaconda, decoding

I have been trying to open multiple json files at once then write them back in python with this code but its giving me error:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

the code:

```
def get_children(node):
  for child in node['children']:
     yield child
      for grandchild in get_children(child):
         yield grandchild

cell_info= open('/Users/massess/Desktop/assignment/cellinfo.text', 'w')

dir_path = '/Users /massess /Desktop /assignment /json'    
   for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
     cell_info.write("%s" %(filename))
       f = open(os.path.join(dir_path,filename), 'r')
         data = json.load(f)

         #prints the root node  
cell_info.write( "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n"   (data["CellName"],data["Event"],   data["Minutes (E)"], data["X (E)"],   data["Y (E)"]))

# prints all children of the root node
for child in get_children(data):
    cell_info.write( "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" %(child["CellName"],     child["Event"], child["Minutes (E)"], child["X (E)"], child["Y (E)"]))

cell_info.close()
```

However, when i use this code to open one specific json file, it works!

```
f = open('path\\to\\.json', 'r')
data = json.load(f)
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It matters in Python. And why are there spaces in the pathes?

Comment: Can you fix the indentations in the posted code? `os.listdir` lists subdirectories as well as files. You may want to use `os.path.isfile` file to filter them out. Does that directory also contain non-json files? Do the json files follow a pattern, such as ending with .json? If so, maybe `glob.glob("yourpath/*.jsoin")` is the best choice. In any case, print out the filename that fails and look at that one.

Comment: @tdelaney i tried both of what you said and then it gives me the same error

same error when i try either solution, i also fixed the indentation

Comment: @KlausD. I did, i may have done it wrong i am fairly new to python

Comment: I have also tried the path.isfile and it gives me this error 

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

@tdelaney

Comment: spaces in filenames matter. Do you really have a bunch of directories with a space as their last character (eg: "/Users ")?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the indentation still being broken, you could add a `print(f.name)` before the call to `json.load()` to see what file triggers the error. That might give you a hint at the problem.

To check whether the file content is valid JSON, you may have it [checked by a linter](http://jsonlint.com/).
dtk